# I have a dental health policy and I have a general health policy that includes dental. Can I claim on both?

Tags: united-kingdom, health-insurance

I had to have a crown for £500. I claimed through the specialist dental insurance. They paid out £350. Can I now claim on the other general insurance policy for the £150 that wasn't covered? I know I mustn't benefit financially from a claim ie claim more than the loss. I feel that I am paying in to both schemes so I should be able to claim on both. 
I would be grateful for clarification - I don't want to submit a claim that flags me as being fraudulent!

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. The Ts and Cs of both policies almost certainly exclude any cover for “double insured” procedures, but you would have to read the small print to be sure. Also the general health policy might only cover dental *accidents* rather than routine treatments etc.

It might be better to ask “Should I keep paying for dental cover when dental cover is already provided by my health policy?” - to which I would say again, read the small print to work out which policy is better and only keep the specific dental cover if it’s giving you something over and above that provided by the general cover.

Comment: Wouldn't they generally exclude cover for sums you can *recover* under another policy, rather than just a blanket exclusion on claims?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam quite possibly, but then you are in the situation where both insurers decline to cover the procedure because the other one covers it. I really don’t think there’s an easy win here.

Comment: @Vicky: But then you *couldn't* recover under the other policy, so both policies would provide coverage again.  Catch-22

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the case. Some policies will cover the excess not covered by the other policies.

Comment: Is there no UK-equivalent to the practice of coordinating benefits when they overlap? The scenario presented in the question is quite typical in the US and the answer would be, "yes - go ahead and claim the remaining amount to the secondary policy."